# Acer Swift 1 randomly shuts down when moved (Acer SF114-32)

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown

I have an issue with an Acer Swift 1 laptop.

It sometimes switches off when moved. It can even turn off from touching the keyboard.

When powering back on, I must hold down the power button and sometimes even press the battery power button with a paper clip in order to restore power.

My first idea was some kind of interlock switch falsely detecting the opening of the back cover. But this is not the solution as Acer Swift 1 doesn’t have an interlock switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated and solved my problem.  There is a metal cover inside the laptop that is held in place by a thin piece of metal. It had broken off and was freely moving inside and causing a short circuit. There is some burned plastic and black stains on the metal from the electricity going through it.

It's the small sheet of metal next to the power input and USB ports.

My solution:

1. Removed screws holding the back cover (T6 "asterisk" screw, but 1.2mm flat head screwdriver worked too)
2. Removed the back cover (used an expired credit card to gently pry it open)
3. Removed the loose metal cover (see images). It fell off without much effort.

The metal is just a cover, so I didn't really need it and the computer works just fine without it. If I was going to leave it in there, I would use electrical insulating tape to fix it in place and ideally cover all the edges of the metal with an insulator.

See the images below.

[image: Location of the loose metal cover]

[image: Detail image of the cover and burn marks]

[image: Detail image of the circuit without the cover]